# a.s. convergence to constant and expectation

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, almost-everywhere

Is it true that, if $X_n$ converges a.s. to a constant $c$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(X_n) = c$? If yes, please, can you prove that?

**Update**: If it is false, is there a condition I can set to prove that it is true?

Comment: As stated $\mathbb{E}(X_n) = c$ a.s. clearly need not be true as $X_n \to c$ a.s. is a statement about convergence.  Did you intend $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(X_n) = c$?

Comment: Thanks @Henry. I just updated. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this was true. Then we would get the statement that if $|X_n - X| \to 0$ a.s., then $E(|X_n - X|) \to 0$. This is saying that almost sure convergence implies $L^1$ convergence. But this is false; convergence a.s. does not imply convergence in $L^1$. One counterexample is $X_n = n1_{(0, 1/n)}$ defined on $[0, 1]$. $X_n \to 0$ a.s. but $E(X_n) = \int_{0}^{1}n1_{(0, 1/n)} = 1$.

Comment: Thanks. In your example, what is the random variable? Also, I am not sure to understang the beginning. I know that this is false in general. But what if X is a constant?

Comment: Is your random variable $f_n(u)$ where $u$ is uniform on $[0, 1]$?

Comment: @Ari.stat I added more details to my answer. The point is that you can deduce the theorem for arbitrary $X$ if you know it holds for constant $X$.

Comment: I am using the Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]$. So yes, you can think that $X_n = n1_{(0, 1/n)}(U)$, where $U$ is uniform on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Great. So maybe if $X_n$ is bounded it is true?

Comment: @Ari.stat If there is a random variable $Y \geq 0$ with $E(Y) < \infty$ and $|X_n| \leq Y$ for all $n$, then $E(X_n) \to E(c) = c$ as $n \to \infty$. This is the DCT: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem